# Filtering out duplicate emails in Postfix

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to filter out duplicate email messages in Postfix?

Let's define the duplicate as the message sent to the same recipient with the same subject (possibly, same message body?) within N seconds, where N is configurable parameter.

The need came from misdesigned/misconfigured software that e.g. allows recending registration email 100 times with 1 second interval. Of course in ideal world, each piece of software shoud be fixed, but in non-ideal world, it's the email admin that has to deal with the consequences of the mess caused (de-blacklisting company email etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be possible just using postfix - but there would be multiple ways you could write code/script this functionality into postfix (albeit not trivially)

I've not tested this particular method of injection but something like:

write your filter script/program - ie something to query if there has been a recent email of the sort sent, conditionally continue processing the email and then add this to the recent email list (and periodically clean up said list).  you might want to simply do logs/queries against a database table, and have a cron script cleaning it up periodically?

The script would input an email, then check it, then exit or reinject it into the system for further processing using sendmail.   Something crudely like

```
 #/path/to/interpreter

 pseudocode to write write date to temporary file or memory

 pseudocode to grep input for whatever is considered a match, check
 against database, and record new line in database

 pseudocode to reinject email using sendmail, for example with a command like
 if [ message to be sent ]
      cat message | /usr/sbin/sendmail "$@"
      exit $?
 else
      exit 1
```

You then modify /etc/postfix/main.cf   and add an appropriate lines to call the filter to the "smtp" line, or, if you are using an alternative port to send email from this application you can add it.   An example would be:

Modify the smtp line to call the filter by adding an additional line -

```
 smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -     smtpd
 -o content_filter=dupfilter:
```

Then add a something to call dupfilter

```
  dupfilter   unix    -   n    n   -   - pipe
   flags=Rq user=scriptowner argv=/path/to/filter ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

I came across https://www.howtoforge.com/add-disclaimers-to-outgoing-emails-with-altermime-postfix-debian-etch which might be useful as a template format, although its trying to do something a bit different.

Comment: Which part of Postfix would need to be extended? Would it be a plugin or codebase change?

Comment: Check updated answer!